# Change language of web content in liferay

Tags: liferay

I would like to change language of web content in liferay. So I tried to change language programatically from en_EN to sk_SK (Slovak) this way:

```
$themeDisplay.getLanguageId() // there it is en_EN
$themeDisplay.setLanguageId('sk_SK')
$themeDisplay.getLanguageId() // there it is sk_SK
```

same it is with this code

```
#set ($locale=$localeUtil.fromLanguageId("sk_SK"))
$themeDisplay.setLocale($locale)
$themeDisplay.getLocale()
```

But the web content didn't change. Do you know why?

If this is not clear I will try to give you an example: On the top of web-page are usually some language buttons, so you can switch between more languages. I want to do same in liferay. So I have one WebContent with more translations and with this buttons I want to change language/translation of webContent.

Answer (score 2):

> On the top of web-page are usually some language buttons, so you can
>   switch between more languages. I want to do same in liferay. So I have
>   one WebContent with more translations and with this buttons I want to
>   change language/translation of webContent.

If i'm not wrong Liferay already provide such functionality out-of-the-box. You don't need to do it with pragmatically.

[image]

Use Liferay's **navigation** portlet to switch the languages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but I would like to add it into my code, into *.vm file. So this is my solution (finally I found it)

```
<div id="language-portlet">
    #set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portlet-setup-show-borders', 'true'))
    #set ($VOID = $theme.runtime("82", '', $velocityPortletPreferences.toString()))
    #set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.reset())
</div>
```

It show possible translations on your web-page. (For me it is flags)

Comment: Liferay already provides the language portlet, which you can drag-n-drop into any site page. Why embeds the portlet into VM??

Comment: Becouse I didnt know it until now :-).

Comment: I guess, its never too late to pick the correct way. Use the standard approach that Liferay provides.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to override this property

```
locale.default.request=false
company.default.locale=sk_SK
```

is `portal-ext.proprties` file